# Is 'pago en especie" the right usage in Latin America for payment in beans?

Tags: modismos

Back in the late 80s early 90s I spent  time working with some Swiss and Colombian associates doing field work for the UN counting turtle  eggs on the Nicaraguan Pacific beaches .

I was there a couple weeks about  2 Km  away from the Cost Rica border, but then  2 months more in Managua working on programming the data , and learned a little Spanish along the way.

I became aware of some local (Sandinista) laws that required the *patron* to do part payment in...

***pago en especie****?

My wife who works for FEWS said that is the correct term. Is there a more local Latin American usage for this custom?

---

****It means that monthly salaries needed to include like 1 gallon of oil, 5 kilos of rice, and a similar amount of raw beans.***

Comment: beans in the most fraught term in Spanish, fyi. The food I mean. There are about six different terms for them: frijoles, abichuelas, etc. https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-espagnol/kind/20326

Comment: There are many words for them from country to country, but there tends to only be one word used per region.

Answer (score 4):

Este termino "**pago en especie**" se usa en Colombia, y se refiere a cuando el pago por un trabajo que realiza una persona no se hace con dinero sino con algún bien, un objeto o un beneficio.

Ejemplo:
Un alto ejecutivo recibe un dinero por su salario y el pago en especie podría ser que la empresa le suministra un vehículo el cual es pagado por la empresa.

Comment: OP knows what "pago en especie" means. He's asking about its usage in Latinoamerica and if there is another way of expressing such term. Maybe you should state at least that you're from Bogotá and that there the term is used.

Comment: pago en especie es un término formal en economia.

Answer (score 1):

Pago en especie means: payment in kind

in kind [payment]   en especie

[Larousse English Spanish Dictionary](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-espagnol/kind/20326)